# Gyroscope animation on a 8x8 matrix

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

so I've been trying to make this primary flight display that's on every plane, but on my raspberry pi Sense hat. Simply it just shows at what angle the nose is piched and how much the plane is banking. I managed to make it work when pitching the Pi forward and backwards (it's pretty hard coded) but I dont know how I could make it work with both tilting and pitching the Pi. Im not even sure if it's possible except for hard coding everything.

here's the code:

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import time

sense = SenseHat()

brown = [153, 76, 0]
blue = [0, 128, 255]


def neutral():
    a = b = c = d = blue
    e = f = g = h = brown
    grid = [
    a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a,
    b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b,
    c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
    d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d,
    e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e,
    f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f,
    g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g,
    h, h, h, h, h, h, h, h
    ]
    sense.set_pixels(grid)

def onedegfrwrd():
    a = b = c = blue
    d = e = f = g = h = brown
    grid = [
    a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a,
    b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b,
    c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
    d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d,
    e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e,
    f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f,
    g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g,
    h, h, h, h, h, h, h, h
    ]
    sense.set_pixels(grid)

def twodegfrwrd():
    a = b = blue
    c = d = e = f = g = h = brown
    grid = [
    a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a,
    b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b,
    c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
    d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d,
    e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e,
    f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f,
    g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g,
    h, h, h, h, h, h, h, h
    ]
    sense.set_pixels(grid)

def threedegfrwrd():
    a = blue
    b = c = d = e = f = g = h = brown
    grid = [
    a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a,
    b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b,
    c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
    d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d,
    e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e,
    f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f,
    g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g,
    h, h, h, h, h, h, h, h
    ]
    sense.set_pixels(grid)

def mcas():
    a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = brown
    grid = [
    a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a,
    b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b,
    c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
    d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d,
    e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e,
    f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f,
    g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g,
    h, h, h, h, h, h, h, h
    ]
    sense.set_pixels(grid)

def onedegback():
    a = b = c = d = e = blue
    f = g = h = brown
    grid = [
    a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a,
    b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b,
    c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
    d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d,
    e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e,
    f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f,
    g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g,
    h, h, h, h, h, h, h, h
    ]
    sense.set_pixels(grid)

def twodegback():
    a = b = c = d = e = f = blue
    g = h = brown
    grid = [
    a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a,
    b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b,
    c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
    d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d,
    e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e,
    f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f,
    g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g,
    h, h, h, h, h, h, h, h
    ]
    sense.set_pixels(grid)

def threedegback():
    a = b = c = d = e = f = g= blue
    h = brown
    grid = [
    a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a,
    b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b,
    c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
    d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d,
    e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e,
    f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f,
    g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g,
    h, h, h, h, h, h, h, h
    ]
    sense.set_pixels(grid)

def fullback():
    a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = blue
    grid = [
    a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a,
    b, b, b, b, b, b, b, b,
    c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
    d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d,
    e, e, e, e, e, e, e, e,
    f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f,
    g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g,
    h, h, h, h, h, h, h, h
    ]
    sense.set_pixels(grid)

while True:
    orientation = sense.get_orientation_degrees()
    y = orientation['roll']
    y = round(y, 1)


    if 80 <= y <= 100:
        neutral()
        print("Stabelized")
    if 60<= y <=80:
        onedegfrwrd()
    if 40 <= y <=60:
        twodegfrwrd()
    if 20 <= y <= 40:
        threedegfrwrd()
        print("PULL UP")
    if 0 <= y <= 20:
        mcas()
        print("PULL UP")
    if 350 <= y <= 359:
        sense.clear()


    if 100 <= y <= 120:
        onedegback()
    if 120 <= y <= 140:
        twodegback()
    if 140 <= y <= 160:
        threedegback()
    if 160 <= y <= 180:
        fullback()
```

just ignore my wierd variable names ;)

Comment: it is not clear what exactly you are asking for. Do you want to know how to do this with less hard coding? please provide clarification.

Comment: This code fills half of the 8x8 matrix with brown and half with blue, the more I tilt the Pi backwards the more blue it becomes and less brown lines are on the matrix (indicating that it's pointing more towards the sky and not the ground) just like on any airplane. This code does also only work when tilting it backwards and forwards, and I don't know how to make it work with tilting it to the sides, so that the line (where the brown and blue meets) would be parallel to ground, like a gyroscope. If you need further explanation, I can upload a video showing what I mean.